# Mat (logic) operator '>=' in OpenCV 2.3

Tags: opencv

I run a demo code from OpenCV 2.3, distrans.cpp and there is a line of code I barely figure out what it means:

```
Mat edge = gray >= edgeThresh, dist, labels, dist8u;
```

It is used like a thresholding operation but I don't know how it works or even to name & google it.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`operator >=` overload for cv::Mat maps the operation to call to [`cv::compare`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.3/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#compare) with the relevant comparison key.

The `cv::compare` function returns a mask (`cv::Mat` of `CV_8U` depth) where all elements satisfying the condition (if element of `gray` has a value not less than `edgeThresh` in your case) are set to `0xFF` and the other elements are zero.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but I guess the answer is not complete yet. what's with the part "edgeThresh, dist, labels, dist8u", the "," ?? whereas with 1 matrix, it is understood like what you said. Here, with many matrices ??

Comment: It's just a C++. Several variables are declared at the same line. The first has an initialization.

Comment: great thanks! I see now, so simple. I didn't know the operator can be used this way