# Boolean operator in cv::Mat class in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, operators, boolean, computer-vision

I am trying to write a big test macro that does some sanity check on my class behaviour (involving constructors, destructors). My code (portion) looks like the following:

```
  TEST(basic_getters_setters_contructors) { // Macro name)

  myNameSpace::myClass mc(cv::Mat::ones(1,2,CV_32S),cv::Mat::zeros(4,8,CV_32S));
  CHECK_EQUAL(false, mc.item1 == NULL);
  //.......Rest of the checks
```

When I build it, I get the compiler error:

```
error C2678: binary '!': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type   
'cv::MatExpr' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

I am pretty certain that the error comes from that line not anywhere else. I tried to use intellisense and found out that the `mc.item1 == NULL` evaluates as a `cv::MatExpr` object. There is a public member called `flag` in `cv::MatExpr` class. Is that the one I should check to see if it is 0 (false) or 1(true)? Or is there any other (and specific) way to do it?

Please don't vote me down if it is a silly question :(...
Kind Regards,

Comment: If you want to check whether a matrix has been populated then the mymat.empty() returns true if the matrix has no elements. See http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-empty

Comment: I've also found the [cv::compare](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=compare#compare) function which may be of interest. See [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9783538/769220).

Comment: You forgot to state what the purpose of your check is.

Comment: actually, if I do this `CHECK_EQUAL(false, &mc.item1 == null)` it works! I think I need to reference it.

Comment: @etarion       Thanks for pointing that out, I am checking if item1, which is of type cv::Mat is null. This kind of proves that myClass instance exists/doesn't exist!