# What does that expression mean in C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I faced one time in an opencv code this expression:

```
Mat bimage = image >= sliderPos;
```

Known that `sliderPos` is an integer.

What does that mean please.

Thanks in advance

ADDITION: of course the type of `image` is `cv::Mat`

Comment: Look for the `>=` operator overload in the data type of the `image` variable.

Comment: What is the type of `image`? My guess would be that `bimage` ends up containing a matrix whose elements indicate whether the corresponding pixel value in `image` is greater or equal to `sliderPos` (but that's just a guess).

Comment: Please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783538/mat-logic-operator-in-opencv-2-3 and here: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to tell without knowing the type of `image`, but according to the OpenCV documentation, I think this line converts `image` into a black and white image, using `sliderPos` as a threshold to determine which pixels will be black.

From [the OpenCV documentation about matrices](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrix-expressions):

> Comparison: A cmpop B, A cmpop alpha, alpha cmpop A, where cmpop is
>   one of :  >, >=, ==, !=, <=, <. The result of comparison is an 8-bit
>   single channel mask whose elements are set to 255 (if the particular
>   element or pair of elements satisfy the condition) or 0.

Comment: image is of type cv::Mat and I saw in documentation that >= is cv::compare, but how come that cv:Mat type can be compared to an integer (threshold)?

Comment: @abualbara Because it has overloaded comparisons that compare each element in the matrix with a scalar.

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
Mat bimage = image >= sliderPos;
```

tests whether `image` is larger or equal to `sliderPos` (which usually yields a `bool`) and assigns the result of the test to the newly created variable `bimage` of type `Mat`.

If the `>=` operator is overloaded for `(decltype(image), int)`, it might not yield a `bool`. If this is the case, look in the documentation of the type of `image` for details. In any case, it yields something, from wich a `Mat` can be constructed.