# OpenCV Mat (comparison) operators documentation

Tags: opencv, operator-overloading

Do you know where one could find documentation for cv::Mat operators, like `<`, `<=` etc? My current doubt is to know if the `<` operator returns ones or `~0` values (`=255` for a uint8_t image, `=65535` for a uint16_t image and so on). Reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9783817/2436175), it is implied that the expected behaviour is the one given by the equivalent [compare](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=compare#compare) call. But I struggle to find a reference in the OpenCV documentation.

I tried to google:

> opencv mat operator documentation

Comment: **`MatExpr`**..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right search term was Matrix Epressions.

From OpenCV 2 [Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrixexpressions):

> Comparison: `A cmpop B`, `A cmpop alpha`, `alpha cmpop A`, where `cmpop` is
>   one of :  `>`, `>=`, `==`, `!=`, `<=`, `<`.
>
> The result of comparison is an 8-bit
>   single channel mask whose elements are set to 255 (if the particular
>   element or pair of elements satisfy the condition) or 0.

In OpenCV 3 the documentation about Matrix Expressions is scattered in the page [Operations on arrays](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html). There is a collection of Matrix Expression here, but with empty documentation! In particular to know what the `<` operator does, one has to check the documentation of  [`cv::compare`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga303cfb72acf8cbb36d884650c09a3a97):

> When the comparison result is true, the corresponding element of
>   output array is set to 255. The comparison operations can be replaced
>   with the equivalent matrix expressions:
>
> ```
> Mat dst1 = src1 >= src2; 
> Mat dst2 = src1 < 8;
> ...
> ```